# RadioButton inside Update Panel causing postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I am putting the following controls inside an update panel so that the whole page does not refresh. When clicking the button, the page does not refresh but when I try to change the radio button, the page refreshes and causes a full postback. Here is my code:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager" runat="Server" EnablePartialRendering="true" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelToggle" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="radioOn" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" GroupName="toggle" Text="On" OnCheckedChanged="radioOn_CheckedChanged" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="radioOff" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" GroupName="toggle" Text="Off" OnCheckedChanged="radioOff_CheckedChanged" />
        <asp:Button ID="testButton" runat="server" OnClick="mybutton_click"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Does setting `UpdateMode="Always"` in your `UpdatePanel` make a difference?

Comment: Do you need the AutoPostBack="true" in your radio buttons? Can you set it to false?

Comment: @jadarnel27 I tried both `UpdateMode="Always"` and `UpdateMode="Conditional"`, none of them works

Comment: @Krishna Yes I need it, because if I set it to false, the `OnCheckedChanged` method is not invoked

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depending on your requirement you can control post backs by adding triggers. Use [AsyncPostBackTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger.aspx) when you want to update only the update panel content. If you need full post back use [PostBackTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.postbacktrigger.aspx).

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelToggle" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="radioOn" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" GroupName="toggle" Text="On" OnCheckedChanged="radioOn_CheckedChanged" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="radioOff" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" GroupName="toggle" Text="Off" OnCheckedChanged="radioOff_CheckedChanged" />
        <asp:Button ID="testButton" runat="server" OnClick="mybutton_click"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="radioOn" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="radioOff" />
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="testButton" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```